# Is this a valid proof of the chain rule for single variable functions?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification, alternative-proof

Let

- $f$ be a continuous and differentiable function
- $\vec{u}=<x, f(x)>$
- $\vec{v}=<x(t),f(t)>$
- $x(t)=t$

Then,
$$\vec{u}=\vec{v}$$
$$\frac{d\vec{u}}{dx}=\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}$$
$$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{\frac{df}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$$
$$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{df}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$$

I've seen lots of other proofs that important subtleties need to be considered whereas here they seem to vanish simply because $\frac{dx}{dt}=1$.

Thanks for any feedback :)

Comment: This seems to prove the chain rule for any $f\circ g$, as long as $g$ is the identify function ...

Comment: @Troposphere I see, thanks! Any thoughts on how to generalize?

Comment: @Troposphere I was thinking that () can be any function that for some t, ⃗ =⃗.

Comment: For _vector_ analysis, you'll want to treat the case where $g$ takes values in $\mathbb R^n$ instead of in $\mathbb R$. The _conclusion_ you're aiming for should include a sum over partial derivatives, and it doesn't look feasible to arrive at that by formal manipulation of $\frac{d\cdot}{d\cdot}$ symbols.

Comment: @Troposphere I am interested in ℝ alone. Sorry I did not made that clear.